# code runs more every click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I want to make page scroll when I click by mouse. But when I click more than one time the function runs again. I want to run it one time only. That idea came to me when I was read article about `scrollBy`.

How can I fix this?

*Note :* I tried (onmouseover) event

```
window.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    var m = setInterval(function () {
        window.scrollBy(0,1);
        console.info(m);
    },4);
    window.onmousemove = function () {
        clearInterval(m);
    };
};
```

Comment: [This article](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `m` that holds the interval is defined in the function scope for `window.onclick`, which makes it unavailable from within `window.onmousemove`. Move your variable definition to the global scope, then it's available from both functions:

```
var m;

window.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    m = setInterval(function () {
        window.scrollBy(0,1);
        console.info(m);
    },4);
};

window.onmousemove = function () {
    if (m) {
        clearInterval(m);
    }
};
```

**Edit** Having read your question again, you say you only want this function to run once. In that case, add a check to see if it's already run:

```
var m;
var hasRun = false;

window.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";

    if (!hasRun) {
        m = setInterval(function () {
            window.scrollBy(0,1);
            console.info(m);
        },4);

        hasRun = true;
    }
};

window.onmousemove = function () {
    if (m) {
        clearInterval(m);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Fot Help . But I made a small edit to make it run again by this code ` var m;
var hasRun = false;

window.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";

    if (!hasRun) {
        m = setInterval(function () {
            window.scrollBy(0,1);
            console.info(m);
        },4);

        hasRun = true;
    }
};

window.onmousemove = function () {
    if (m) {
        clearInterval(m);
    }
    var hasRun = false;
};`

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to : rickdenhaan
This Is The Right Code :

```
var m;
var hasRun = false;

window.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";

    if (!hasRun) {
        m = setInterval(function () {
            window.scrollBy(0,1);
            console.info(m);
        },4);

        hasRun = true;
    }
};

window.onmousemove = function () {
    if (m) {
        clearInterval(m);
    }
    var hasRun = false;
};
```